# why did php yii2 active record query giving duplicates?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I'm developinga a classifieds portal where user can post their ads. We have a option to chat with user for ads.

I store chats in a table called "tb_inbox" it looks like this
[Screenshot of Inbox table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZRwc.png)

I have a area of my chats there i want to show the ads user chatting to. user will be sender or receiver. but based on
ad_id i want to list the ads in my chat.

But now it shows many duplicates with my query. it shows same ads repeatedly for each message

my code

```
    $messages=Inbox::find()->where(['sender_id'=>$user_id])
                        ->orWhere(['recipient_id'=>$user_id])
                        ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
                        ->all();
```

How I can show ads what I'm receiving and sending based on ad_id?
The user will be sender or receiver

thanks

Comment: try group by ad_id

Comment: then it shows only one user conversation

Comment: try to group by ad_id, sender, recipient

Answer (score 0):

try with one() or distinct()

```
$messages=Inbox::find()->where(['sender_id'=>$user_id])
                    ->orWhere(['recipient_id'=>$user_id])
                    ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
                    ->one();

 $messages=Inbox::find()->where(['sender_id'=>$user_id])
                    ->orWhere(['recipient_id'=>$user_id])
                    ->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC])
                    ->distinct()->all();
```